# Update any date to the current date in a text file

Tags: bash, shell-script, text-processing, date

I have a text file which contains several occurrences of dates. All the dates are written in the format `Mon-DD-YYYY`. I have to update all these dates in the current date keeping the format `Mon-DD-YYYY`.

The scripting language is `bash`. One big problem is that I have no idea how to match a specific format date with `sed`, `awk`, `bash` built-in functions, etc.

Could you help me, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set `current_date=$(date +"%m-%d-%Y")` or to whatever date you want and then run

```
sed -i.bak "s/[0-9]\{2\}-[0-9]\{2\}-[0-9]\{4\}/$current_date/g" your_file.txt
```

With this, you can match any date in a file and replace it with current_date

The `sed` command in this case works like: `sed "s/tobereplace/replacement/g"`. The `g` at the end stands for global, that means every occurrence of the tobereplace pattern will be replaced by replacement.

For tobereplaced the regex pattern **`[0-9]\{2\}-[0-9]\{2\}-[0-9]\{4\}`** is used, which translates to

- `[0-9]` any number from 0 to 9
- `\{2\}` two times
- hyphen
- the same again and the same again but four times `\{4\}`

**Edit:**
As FelixJN mentioned in the comment, you probably wanted the month as a string, for that you would use %b in the date command and replace the first part of the regex like this:

```
current_date=$(date "+%b-%d-%Y")
sed -Ei "s/[A-Z][a-z]\{2\}-[0-9]\{2\}-[0-9]\{4\}/$current_date/g" your_file.txt
```

In this case, the regex works like this:

- `[A-Z]`  Matches any uppercase letter from A to Z.
- `[a-z]\{2\}` Matches any lowercase letter from a to z two times

The rest is the same as mentioned above

Comment: I think `Mon` in OP's request asks for using `%b` and  `[A-Z][a-z]\{2\}` for the month.

Comment: I missed that, in that case you are right, of course

Comment: @FelixJN with `Mon-DD-YYYY` I mean, for instance, `Jan-14-2023`

Comment: @user9952796 I fixed my regex for you. If this answers your question, please mark is as the correct answer.

Comment: To reduce potential false matches, the regex might be `/(Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{4}/` -- use `sed -E` to not have to escape the regex characters

Comment: @glennjackman I was about to ask it XD

Comment: I doubt any of this is the right approach. Today the file has several dates which should be replaced with current. Tomorrow, a new version of the file might mention some date in the same format which should not be replaced, but wrongly will be.  Blindly replacing regexes absolutely everywhere in a file, which only match the item you are looking for without any context, is rarely a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

*If you're starting from a numeric (2-digit) month:*

```perl
~$ raku -pe 's:g/ \d**2 \- \d**2 \- \d**4 /{Date.today.mm-dd-yyyy("-")}/;'  file
```

*If you're starting from an alphabetic (3-letter) month:*

```perl
~$ raku -pe 'BEGIN my %h = [Z=>] 1..12, <Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec>;   \
             s:g/ <{%h.values}> \- \d**2 \- \d**4  /{ join "-", %h{Date.today.month}, Date.today.day, Date.today.year }/;'  file
```

Sample Input:

```
Delaware  Dec-07-1787;      Pennsylvania  Dec-12-1787;      New Jersey  Dec-18-1787;        Georgia  Jan-02-1788;
Connecticut  Jan-09-1788;       Massachusetts  Feb-06-1788;     Maryland  Apr-28-1788;      South Carolina  May-23-1788;
New Hampshire  Jun-21-1788;     Virginia  Jun-25-1788;      New York  Jul-26-1788;      North Carolina  Nov-21-1789;
Rhode Island  May-29-1790;      Vermont  Mar-04-1791;       Kentucky  Jun-01-1792;      Tennessee  Jun-01-1796;
Ohio  Mar-01-1803;      Louisiana  Apr-30-1812;     Indiana  Dec-11-1816;       Mississippi  Dec-10-1817;
Illinois  Dec-03-1818;      Alabama  Dec-14-1819;       Maine  Mar-15-1820;     Missouri  Aug-10-1821;
Arkansas  Jun-15-1836;      Michigan  Jan-26-1837;      Florida  Mar-03-1845;       Texas  Dec-29-1845;
Iowa  Dec-28-1846;      Wisconsin  May-29-1848;     California  Sep-09-1850;        Minnesota  May-11-1858;
Oregon  Feb-14-1859;        Kansas  Jan-29-1861;        West Virginia  Jun-20-1863;     Nevada  Oct-31-1864;
Nebraska  Mar-01-1867;      Colorado  Aug-01-1876;      North Dakota  Nov-02-1889;      South Dakota  Nov-02-1889;
Montana  Nov-08-1889;       Washington  Nov-11-1889;        Idaho  Jul-03-1890;     Wyoming  Jul-10-1890;
Utah  Jan-04-1896;      Oklahoma  Nov-16-1907;      New Mexico  Jan-06-1912;        Arizona  Feb-14-1912;
Alaska  Jan-03-1959;        Hawaii  Aug-21-1959;
```

Sample Output:

```
Delaware  Jul-4-2023;       Pennsylvania  Jul-4-2023;       New Jersey  Jul-4-2023;     Georgia  Jul-4-2023;
Connecticut  Jul-4-2023;        Massachusetts  Jul-4-2023;      Maryland  Jul-4-2023;       South Carolina  Jul-4-2023;
New Hampshire  Jul-4-2023;      Virginia  Jul-4-2023;       New York  Jul-4-2023;       North Carolina  Jul-4-2023;
Rhode Island  Jul-4-2023;       Vermont  Jul-4-2023;        Kentucky  Jul-4-2023;       Tennessee  Jul-4-2023;
Ohio  Jul-4-2023;       Louisiana  Jul-4-2023;      Indiana  Jul-4-2023;        Mississippi  Jul-4-2023;
Illinois  Jul-4-2023;       Alabama  Jul-4-2023;        Maine  Jul-4-2023;      Missouri  Jul-4-2023;
Arkansas  Jul-4-2023;       Michigan  Jul-4-2023;       Florida  Jul-4-2023;        Texas  Jul-4-2023;
Iowa  Jul-4-2023;       Wisconsin  Jul-4-2023;      California  Jul-4-2023;     Minnesota  Jul-4-2023;
Oregon  Jul-4-2023;     Kansas  Jul-4-2023;     West Virginia  Jul-4-2023;      Nevada  Jul-4-2023;
Nebraska  Jul-4-2023;       Colorado  Jul-4-2023;       North Dakota  Jul-4-2023;       South Dakota  Jul-4-2023;
Montana  Jul-4-2023;        Washington  Jul-4-2023;     Idaho  Jul-4-2023;      Wyoming  Jul-4-2023;
Utah  Jul-4-2023;       Oklahoma  Jul-4-2023;       New Mexico  Jul-4-2023;     Arizona  Jul-4-2023;
Alaska  Jul-4-2023;     Hawaii  Jul-4-2023;
```

The replacement half uses raku code in a `{...}` curly-brace wrapped codeblock to generate the replacement date. Note: in the recognition domain, the above code (second answer) uses `<{%h.values}>` to generate months. You could use `<alpha>**3` instead, or even @GlennJackman's list of months (in the comments).

---

*Shipley, Samuel. "list of U.S. states’ dates of admission to the union". Encyclopedia Britannica, 11 Feb. 2020, https://www.britannica.com/topic/list-of-U-S-states-by-date-of-admission-to-the-Union-2130026. Accessed 4 July 2023.*

https://docs.raku.org/type/Date
https://docs.raku.org/routine/mm-dd-yyyy
https://raku.org